# Array in body for httr POST request

Tags: r, httr, jsonlite

This curl call works to create a new droplet on Digital Ocean

```
curl -X POST "https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/droplets" \
   -d '{"name":"test3","region":"nyc2","size":"512mb","image":5562742,"ssh_keys":[89103]}' \
   -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" 
   -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

However, I'm having trouble getting an `httr::POST()` request to work only when the parameter `ssh_keys` is given.  In the above method the `ssh_keys` parameter, if given, has to be an array.

I assumed the list of parameters could be passed to the body as, e.g., where the `ssh_keys` parameter is inside a list

```
args <- list(name="test3", region="nyc2", size="512mb", image="5562742", ssh_keys=list(891111))
POST(url, config=auth, body=args)
```

I assume this is what's happening on the inside:

```
jsonlite::toJSON(args)

[1] "{ \"name\" : [ \"test3\" ], \"region\" : [ \"nyc2\" ], \"size\" : [ \"512mb\" ], \"image\" : [ \"5562742\" ], \"ssh_keys\" : [ [ 89103 ] ] }"
```

Which I imagine would work, but perhaps that's not what's happening? Fiddling with the `encode` parameter in `POST` doesn't seem to help.

The curl call works from terminal, but using `httr::POST()` I keep getting the error message

> You specified invalid ssh key ids for Droplet creation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
req <- POST(
    url = "https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/droplets",
    body = toJSON(args, auto_unbox=TRUE),
    add_headers (
        "Content-Type" = "application/json",
        "Authorization" = paste("Bearker", TOKEN)
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, this is almost there, but I still need `ssh_keys` boxed in an array, so I had to `unbox()` all other params, but leave `ssh_keys` boxed. In addition, had to set `encode='json'` in the `POST()` call

Comment: I also had to add `encode='json'`.  Otherwise I got an error: `Error in named(list(...)) : argument is missing, with no default`

Answer (score 3):

In this specific case,

```
x <- jsonlite::toJSON(args, auto_unbox=TRUE)
cat(x)
```

seems to return the correct format (assuming the problem is not with the headers) so them

```
POST(url, config=auth, body=x)
```

should send the correct request.