# How to specify httr::GET array query

Tags: php, arrays, r, httr

I am trying to compose an httr::GET query where I must use a bracketed (array) query where the url resembles:

```
 #target = "http://example.com?abc[]=123"
```

This strategy does not seem to work:

```
 baseurl = "http://example.com"
 qy = list(abc="123")
 httr::GET(baseurl,query=qy)
```

R complains about invalid characters if I try:

```
qy = list(abc[]="123")
```

See also:
[Is array syntax using square brackets in URL query strings valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490326/is-array-syntax-using-square-brackets-in-url-query-strings-valid)

[Array in body for httr POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25609041/array-in-body-for-httr-post-request)

Comment: Its not that the first example throws an error, its that it does not return the same thing as the target.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use

```
GET(url, query = list("abc[]" = 133))
```