# json array in httr post

Tags: r, httr, jsonlite

I am trying to pass a json array in a `POST` request using the `httr` package. However I get a `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request` because of the formatting of the array. Here's how I build the request:

```
decos <- list(name="ais-static-journey")
decos <- jsonlite::toJSON(decos, auto_unbox = TRUE) #Have also tried decos <- toJSON(decos, pretty = TRUE)

body <- list(mmsis=mmsis, startDate= startDate,
             endDate= endDate, decorations = decos)

r <- POST(decoratedurl,body=body, encode="json",add_headers(Authorization=auth), verbose())
```

I also had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25609041/array-in-body-for-httr-post-request).

The error I get is primarily because of the back slashes in the request:

`"decorations":"{\"name\":\"ais-static-journey\"}"}`

This needs to be `"decorations":[{"name":"ais-static-journey"}]`
How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out. This works:

```
decos <- list(list(name="ais-static-journey"))
body <- list(mmsis=mmsis, startDate= startDate,
             endDate= endDate, decorations = decos)
r <- POST(decoratedurl,body=body, encode="json",add_headers(Authorization=auth), verbose())
```